# NaN columns pandas turning into empty row when using pivot_table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I use read_csv to fill a pandas. In this pandas I have a full NaN empty columns and this turns into a problem when I use pivot_table.
Here my situation:

```
d= {'dates': ['01/01/20','01/02/20','01/03/20'], 'country':['Fra','Fra','Fra'], 'val': [np.nan,np.nan,np.nan]} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
piv=df.pivot_table(index='country',values='val',columns='dates')
print(piv)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []
```

I would like to have this :

```
dates    01/01/20  01/02/20  01/03/20
country                              
Fra             NaN         NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from docs, set `dropna = False` [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

```
piv = df.pivot_table(index='country',values='val',columns='dates', dropna=False)
```

---

```
dates    01/01/20  01/02/20  01/03/20
country                              
Fra           NaN       NaN       NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `dropna` argument of `pivot`:

```
df.pivot_table(index='country',columns='dates', values='val', dropna = False)
```

The output is:

```
dates    01/01/20  01/02/20  01/03/20
country                              
Fra           NaN       NaN       NaN
```